# Bit fields and access specifiers

Tags: c++

Is it allowed to specify different access specifiers in c++ for bitfields? ex.:

```
struct S1 {
   unsigned f1    : 2;
   unsigned f2    : 2;
private: // 1
   unsigned f3    : 2;
public: // 2
   unsigned f4    : 2;
};
```

So the question is whether its allowed to specify access specifiers as in lines 1 and 2?

Comment: Sounds like it should be simple enough to cut/paste this into an empty file, and then see what your C++ compiler thinks about it?

Comment: Nothing disallows this. The result depends entirely on your compiler, the standard is very loose about how bit fields are actually implemented.

Comment: It does compile, but I am tracking a strange bug which shows up only on arm compilation and not on x86, so I wonder if maybe something is unspecified in my code

Comment: @mike It depends on what you do with `S1`. There isn't anything wrong with `S1`. Just remember that layout is implementation defined. Adding access specifiers may or may not alter its layout and size.

Comment: _"...The following properties of bit-fields are implementation-defined:.."_ _"Everything about the actual allocation details of bit-fields within the class object"_  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field  So if you need an exact layout check your implementation docs or just use `unsigned int` (or known size type) and bit operators.

Comment: "but I am tracking a strange bug which shows up only on arm compilation" I think it would be more productive to show actual code where bug is detected, without unrelated details obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes, it is.

## Long answer

On the other hand, breaking strict aliasing rules is not. This is a common problem with people just assuming things regarding this and few other C++ language features, then blindly looking for issues in places where there are none.

This "strange" bug you mention in comments smells a lot like you trying to reinterpret cast a std::byte to your struct, which despite "obviously" being possible is undefined behavior. The only strange thing here is immense amount of laziness when dealing with low level data storage that is also painfully apparent in how much effort was actually put into writing this question.

Well, anyway, why would you try to just reinterpret cast a byte to your bit-field structure even if that's not what you're doing? Because it's faster? Than what, your program never even compiling correctly because your compiler assumed that you wouldn't do this? Undefined behavior is undefined, but consequences clearly are.

You have to remember that bit fields are ***not*** portable and are primarily a convenience, not a necessity. If you want speed, you will give up convenience every single time, for example, convenience of assuming that what you're doing will be faster without profiling your code. If you profile your code and identify that all this "complex" conversion between raw bytes that you can send over network or write to disk platform independently is really a bottleneck, you will fall back from bit-fields to manually arranging the bytes, that's the reality we programmers live in.

At the same time, such constructs as in your question are completely worthless, so even if it were not possible to have private bit-fields, it wouldn't be an issue, because raw data (not POD!) should be treated like raw data and if you wanted some specific abstract behavior you'd put this raw data into a real class as a private member with all fields public to the enclosing class and work from there.

But I digress, here's what everyone is painfully aching for while reading this rant-like explanation - a real example that is clear, clean, obvious, correct, platform independent and sane:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

struct packed_struct {
    unsigned a: 2;
    unsigned b: 2;
    unsigned c: 1;
    unsigned d: 2;
    unsigned e: 1;

    packed_struct() noexcept
    : a{},
      b{},
      c{},
      d{},
      e{}
    {}

    // no, this struct is NOT supposed to be a POD, the POD is right here, std::byte, the
    // plainest and oldest data you will ever see
    explicit packed_struct(std::byte raw) noexcept
    // you only need to get this right once
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence
    : a(static_cast<unsigned>(raw) >> 0 & 0b11),
      d(static_cast<unsigned>(raw) >> 2 & 0b11),
      b(static_cast<unsigned>(raw) >> 4 & 0b11),
      e(static_cast<unsigned>(raw) >> 6 &  0b1),
      c(static_cast<unsigned>(raw) >> 7 &  0b1)
      // what is this arbitrary order you ask? well... not all data we get is
      // our own, so it is not always ordered how we might want it to be;
      // in our project we have this stupid rule to order same size fields
      // alphabetically, and while noone likes it, noone wants to challenge
      // whoever made it up, so this will have to do
      // think this is unrealistic? Think again
    {}

    explicit operator std::byte() const noexcept
    {
        std::byte raw{};
        raw |= static_cast<std::byte>(a << 0);
        raw |= static_cast<std::byte>(d << 2);
        raw |= static_cast<std::byte>(b << 4);
        raw |= static_cast<std::byte>(e << 6);
        raw |= static_cast<std::byte>(c << 7);
        return raw;
    }
};

// well, where's the benefit of this if we did it all manually? the answer is
// we did only what we always have to, while compiler did a lot of free and a
// lot more annoying work for us
int main() {
    // there is a clear line between human understandable data
    packed_struct s;
    s.a = 1;
    s.b = 3;
    s.c = 0;
    s.d = 2;
    s.e = 1;

    // and an unintelligible block of bits that noone needs to know the layout of
    // but we do know the layout, we wrote the conversion functions, didn't we?
    // no, I in fact do not know which bit is "3rd" or "7th" or even "29th", 
    // and guess what, I don't care either
    std::byte b = static_cast<std::byte>(s);

    // but can still be effortlessly stored in a file and even moved across
    // systems, ignoring any details including processor architecture...

    // and yet, they can all be converted back and forth effortlessly
    packed_struct r(~b); // you can even mess up the bits in a POD

    // and still get exactly what you expect, no assumptions, ever
    std::cout << "r.a = " << r.a << '\n'  // 2
              << "r.b = " << r.b << '\n'  // 0
              << "r.c = " << r.c << '\n'  // 1
              << "r.d = " << r.d << '\n'  // 1
              << "r.e = " << r.e << '\n'; // 0
}
```

Same can be done with bigger types than `std::byte` and if you understood the basic idea behind this, you will have no problems figuring out how to use exact same logic to encode and decode an `unsigned short`, `long int`... which will work correctly even on systems that have randomized endianness for every byte access as long as there's a compiler that supports it.

Since I wrote this much already, I may aswell give an example for bigger types:

```
unsigned short b{};
std::array<std::byte, 2> bytes;
// <read 2 bytes from somewhere like using fread and a.data()>
```

Here is the only part that ever matters - which byte goes where? No, this has absolutely nothing to do with your CPU architecture and you should not conflate these things. I can write first then second, or second then first, it will all work the same no matter what machine runs this, as long as you are consistent, and I should not need to tell you to be consistent.

```
b |= static_cast<unsigned short>(bytes[0] << 8);
b |= static_cast<unsigned short>(bytes[1] << 0);
packed_struct_2bytes s2(b); // TODO: implement this type
```

The thing to take away here is that the format that you define is for programmers, not machines. Yes, it's "2 bits from 6th bit from 3rd byte", but you have to understand what this actually means. Your CPU could count bytes backwards, or even go back and forth between the ends by treating 4 byte integer type as `{1, 3, 4, 2}` (not to be confused with C array syntax), where `a[2] == 2`. You don't need to know this, just like you don't need to know how bits are packed while using bit-fields feature. We have made up programming languages because dealing with real machines is hard. The downside is that "knowing" things about machines doesn't help you in edge cases, but it shouldn't matter to you, and when it will, you will be the one explaining things to everyone instead of asking questions.

Once you understand these trivial things, all of your "strange bugs" will go away permanently.

And unsurprisingly, you can make any fields private in this struct if you really need this, it will work just fine.